# Unset one duplicate value in array PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I have 2 arrays: Array1 and Array2. As you can see in Array1 I have 2 duplicate values. So what I want to do, is unset one of dublicates (doesn't matter which one) and as a result I need to unset value from Array2 with the same key as already unset value in Array1

```
Array1
(
    [0] => 1331-14-2-45
    [1] => 1344-1-4-22
    **[2] => 1409-1-1-4**
    [4] => 1312-14-1-23
    **[5] => 1409-1-1-4**
    [6] => 1365-10-3-30
)
```

AND

```
Array2
(
    [0] => opticalSignalLevelTooLow1490nm#nemodel.GPON.4.6
    [1] => opticalSignalLevelTooLow1490nm#nemodel.GPON.4.6
    [2] => opticalSignalLevelTooLow1490nm#nemodel.GPON.4.6
    [4] => deviceNotActive#nemodel.GPON.4.6
    [5] => deviceNotActive#nemodel.GPON.4.6
    [6] => opticalSignalLevelTooLow1490nm#nemodel.GPON.4.6
)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php
$array1 = array
(
    0 => '1331-14-2-45',
    1 => '1344-1-4-22',
    2 => '1409-1-1-4',
    4 => '1312-14-1-23',
    5 => '1409-1-1-4',
    6 => '1365-10-3-30',
);
$array1_tmp = $array1;
$array2 = array
(
    0 => 'opticalSignalLevelTooLow1490nm#nemodel.GPON.4.6',
    1 => 'opticalSignalLevelTooLow1490nm#nemodel.GPON.4.6',
    2 => 'opticalSignalLevelTooLow1490nm#nemodel.GPON.4.6',
    4 => 'deviceNotActive#nemodel.GPON.4.6',
    5 => 'deviceNotActive#nemodel.GPON.4.6',
    6 => 'opticalSignalLevelTooLow1490nm#nemodel.GPON.4.6',
);
$array1 = array_unique($array1);
$remove_keys = array_keys(array_diff_key($array1_tmp, $array1));
foreach($remove_keys as $k => $v) {
    unset($array2[$v]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [array_unique()](http://php.net/manual/fr/function.array-unique.php) function, and maybe take a look at the [Array functions list](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.array.php).

Answer (score 0):

Use [array_unique](http://php.net//manual/en/function.array-unique.php) function and [array_diff](http://php.net//manual/en/function.array-diff.php)

```
$uniqueValues = array_unique($inputArray);               //your  first array
$deletedValues = array_diff($inputArray, $uniqueValues);

foreach($deletedValues as $key => $deletedValue){
     unset($secondIput[$key]);                           //you second array
}
```